# Reference kibana's dashboard date range in custom search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hello! Is it possible to reference dashboards date range inside a custom query or filter? eg:

somefield:[dashboard_ldate TO dashboard_hdate] Thank You!

Comment: Yes, but please show what you have tried and what it does give you?

Comment: Yes, thanks. What I'm trying to do is to apply the same range filter used in kibana's top bar but in a different date field. I have an index with two relevant date fields, eg. created and updated. In some cases I need to use one or another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was covered on IRC.  What you're looking for is adding a new index pattern to use the additional date fields.

Each visualization can use a different index pattern, so you can have a good mixture on a dashboard.

Comment: Thank you very much, I agree this is the way to go. But I don't find the way to switch between patterns. Shoud I go to settings > indices and just set the new pattern as default to set it to the new visualization?

Comment: In any case I think it would be great some kind of notation to override dashboard's date range directly when using queries in kibana's search bar, etc

Comment: When you're in Discover, you can select the index pattern on the left side.  When you make a new Visualization, it asks you to select the index pattern right after you select the visualization type.

Comment: This is kinda janky, but it does work to have 3 index patterns - myindex, myinde*, myind*